# Eliminar espacios en blanco entre 2 divs de distintos tamaños

Tags: html, bootstrap

Buen día con todos, me encuentro desarrollando un sitio web en Angular con Bootstrap, y una de mis secciones contiene reseñas de usuarios, pero hay algunas mas cortas que otras, y eso hace que los divs que contienen la información sean de diferentes tamaños, y eso hace que queden espacios en blanco grandes entre los divs, y eso no es estéticamente agradable. La información la cargo desde un array para evitar copiar y pegar código
[image: Estos son los espacios que quedan]

Código HTML:

```
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6" *ngFor="let person of people">
      <div class="review">
        <div class="review-head p-4 bg-white theme-shadow">
          <div class="text-warning">
            <i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i>
            <i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i>
            <i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i>
            <i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i>
            <i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i>
          </div>
          <p>{{person.testimonial}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="review-person mt-4 d-flex align-items-center">
          <img class="rounded-circle" [src]="person.img" style="width: 100px;">
          <div class="ms-3">
            <h5>{{person.name}}</h5>
            <small>{{person.university}}</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Las clases que uso, son clases de bootstrap, los unicos estilos css personalizados que uso son estos:

```
.review-head{
  position: relative;
}
.review small{
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.review-head::after{
  content: "";
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -14px;
  background-color: white;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.review-person{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Como puedo solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes alinear todo con las clases flex de Bootstrap, `d-flex align-items-center` o `d-flex align-items-stretch` podrían ayudarte, te recomiendo revisar en la documentación de tu versión de Bootstrap Docs > Utilities > Flex.